# Very simple NAT question. How does a packet get back out?

Tags: routing, nat, firewall

Sorry for the simplicity of the question, I just need some help.

Lets say I have a NAT rule on my firewall that translates a public IP into a private one (say 195.111.111.2 to 10.1.1.10)

I can understand how the packet traverses the internal network, but lets say an application wants to send a response back. It will have the "source address" and so knows where to send the packet, and will most likely hit some default routes on the way back out until it hits my firewall. How does my firewall know to inject the 195.111.111.2 source address back into the packet?

Do i have to set up two NATs for every NAT or is the one NAT rule implying the reverse translation will be done?

I feel this may be unclear, but hopefully it isn't.

Comment: this question has been answered several times before

Comment: Have you got any examples @MikePennington?

Answer (score 3):

I thought I would answer my own question.

I was referring to DNAT (Destination NAT) where the destination IP is modified.

Here is a simple explanation of what happens to a packet, taken from http://www.mad-hacking.net/documentation/linux/security/iptables/nat.xml

1. A packet arrives at the public address with that address set as its destination address and its source address set to that of the originating host.
2. A DNAT rule is encountered where the destination address of the packet is modified to the internal IP.
3. The firewall host makes a routing decision and sends the packet out of the correct interface destined for the address which was just rewritten. The packet's source address is unchanged and still represents the originating host.
4. The packet arrives at the host we specified. This host then generates a response packet which it sends back to the originating host. As the source address was unchanged it should be sent back via the default gateway which will be the firewall host in the previous step.
5. The packet is received by the firewall host which sees that it is destined for the same host which it just performed the DNAT operation for. It therefore modifies the source address of the returning packet so that it looks like it came from the address it was destined for before it was DNATed in step two.
6. The packet arrives at the host which requested it and, as its source address is the same as that to which the original request was sent, is gratefully received.

In scenarios where default route would send the packet out of a different interface from which it was received, double NATing is the answer. For example this resource http://www.fwbuilder.org/4.0/docs/users_guide5/double_nat.shtml

Comment: The key thing to remember with iptables NAT is that only the first packet of each connection goes through the NAT tables. Once a connection is known any further packets for that connection (in both directions) are simply handled according to the existing mapping.

Answer (score 1):

The NAT'ing device keeps a table of mappings.  As packets are returned to the original sender (the routable IP address that sent them) the NAT device does a lookup in that table to re-address the destination packet with the inside private IP.

Answer (score 0):

Are you coding firewall ? 
This may be helpful

One option can be maintain tables that will contain detail so you will require 4 fields,

`source IP, Source Port, Dest IP, Dest Por`t.

When packet will entered then fields may be like

`201.1.1.10, 80, 195.111.111.2 , 2345`  **let (201.1.1.10, 80 are IP and port of default internet)**

then your firewall will change it to like

```
195.111.111.2, Port of firewall, 10.1.1.10, port of host
```

and when packet will get back to your firewall

```
10.1.1.10, port of host, 195.111.111.2, Port of firewall
```

Comment: I didnt think the firewall would inject itself as the source. I thought the source would stay the same